# Does $\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx} \ln(x)=\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx} \ln|x|$?

Tags: integration, derivatives, indefinite-integrals

For some time, I've seen different solutions for the same problems.

Let $f$ be any continuous function, differenciable on its domain such that,

$$\int \frac{\mathrm d f}{f}=\ln(f)$$

but some authors say,

$$\int \frac{\mathrm d f}{f}=\ln|f|$$

I know that,

$$\displaystyle \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}\ln |x|=\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}\ln \sqrt(x^2)=$$
$$\displaystyle \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}\ln (x^2)^{\frac{1}{2}}=\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}\frac{1}{2}\ln (x^2)=$$
$$\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}\ln (x)$$

And so I concluded that:
$$\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx} \ln|x|=\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx} \ln(x)$$

Can I generalizate that,

$$\int \frac{\mathrm d f}{f}=\ln(f)= \ln|f|$$

Comment: Well, $\ln x$ and $\ln|x|$ has different domain, and indeed the derivative is the same on their common domain, since they are the same on their common domain. Plus, your derivation is not correct  $\frac{d}{dx}\frac{1}{2}\ln x^2 = \frac{d}{dx}\ln |x|$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The functions $\ln x$ and $\ln |x|$ are defined on different regions: The former is defined for positive $x$ while the latter is defined for every non-zero $x$.

Using the chain rule, and the fact the derivative of the absolute value is the signum function one can see that $$\frac{d}{dx} \ln |f(x)| =\frac{1}{|f(x)|} (\text{sgn} f(x)) f'(x).$$
Since $\text{sgn}=\pm1$ we can move it to the denominator, so 
$$\frac{d}{dx} \ln |f(x)| =\frac{1}{(\text{sgn} f(x))|f(x)|} f'(x).$$

And lastly, for any real $t$, $|t| \cdot \text{sgn}t=t$. Thus
$$\frac{d}{dx} \ln |f(x)| =\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}.$$

Which coincides with the derivative of $\ln f(x)$.

To summarize: $\ln f$ and $\ln |f|$ have the same derivative but the second one is defined over a greater set.

Comment: So they are equal for $x>0$. Thanks for the help.